# Is there a way to get info about a built in function in Haskell for Mac

Tags: macos, haskell

I am trying out Haskell for Mac as an alternative to bash and ghci (for learning Haskell). With ghci I can get info about things I see in other people's code. For instance if I wonder about ++ I can write :i followed by ++ and ghci tells me that I can find info in GHC.Base.

[image]

Is there some way to do that in Haskell for Mac?

Comment: Does anything happen if you hover over `++`? From a video it looks like that triggers some information to be shown.

Comment: what video? If I hover over ++ in Playground of Haskell for Mac nothing happens

Comment: not on a mac, but do tooltips as illustrated in [this image from haskellformac.com](http://haskellformac.com/images/functions-and-types-squashed-800-1.jpg) not appear?

Comment: I was checking [this](http://haskellformac.com/haskell-for-mac-learning-haskell.html) which shows some tooltips appearing. I'm not sure about how that works.

Answer (score 2):

Just select and hit Cmd+I.

If I took the time to read the badges appearing I would have spotted it :$

[image]